# Detectar texto copiado

Tags: android

Como executar uma ação sempre que alguém copiar algum texto no *keyboard* do Android?
E teria que usar um service para deixar rodando o tempo todo?

Comment: Que tipo de ação seria executada?

Comment: pegaria o texto copiado e registraria em um banco sqlite @DenerCarvalho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está procurando pelo método `addPrimaryClipChangedListener` do `ClipboardManager`. Ele recebe como parâmetro um `ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener`.

Presumindo que você esteja familiar com Listeners, o código fica mais ou menos assim:

```
final ClipboardManager gerenciadorDeAreaDeTransferencia = 
        (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

gerenciadorDeAreaDeTransferencia.
    addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                        // seu código
                    }
                }
    );
```

Vale notar que isso só funciona a partir da API 11.

Sobre fazer funcionar em segundo plano, você provavelmente vai depender de um service, sim, mas os detalhes disso são assunto pra outra pergunta.

Comment: É isso mesmo, eu já estava usando o ClipboardManager e ClipData, mas não vi os listeners, passou despercebido